# Por que não é possível (facilmente) ocultar membros private?

Tags: c++, encapsulamento

A ocultação da implementação é uma das chaves de uma boa engenharia de software moderna, e crucial na reutilização de código. Por que então, em c++ não é possível ocultar a implementação de dados private? Já que esses dados membros basicamente só poderão ser utilizados por funções membros da classe (ou de amigas). Dado o código usual a seguir:

**private.h**

```
#ifndef PRIVATE_H
#define PRIVATE_H

#include <string>

class OlaMundo {

public: 
   OlaMundo(std::string);

   void mostrarMsg();

private:
   std::string mensagem;
};

#endif
```

**private.cpp**

```
#include "private.h"
#include <iostream>

OlaMundo::OlaMundo(std::string msgArg) {

   mensagem = msgArg;
}

void OlaMundo::mostrarMsg() {

   std::cout << "Olá, " << mensagem << "!" << std::endl;
}
```

Teste: **main.cpp**

```
 #include "private.h"

 int main()
{
   OlaMundo ola("Rafael");

   ola.mostrarMsg();
}
```

Por que não é possível declarar os dados membros private (`std::string mensagem`) na implementação (private.cpp)? Não seria uma melhor engenharia de software deixar somente a interface pública disponível e encapsular o comportamento interno das funções - como é pretendido?

**Observação:** O código private.cpp poderia ser feito da forma (retirando-se o mebro private do cabeçalho correspondente:

```
#include "private.h"
#include <iostream>

std::string mensagem;

OlaMundo::OlaMundo(std::string msgArg) {

   mensagem = msgArg;
}

void OlaMundo::mostrarMsg() {

    std::cout << "Olá, " << mensagem << "!" << std::endl;
}
```

isso poderia ser considerado como uma boa engenharia em C++? O dado se tornou "private" por cabeçalho e não por definição de classe. Por que é necessário por os dados privates nos headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Por que então, em c++ não é possível ocultar a implementação de dados private?
>
> Por que é necessário por os dados privates nos headers?

Isso é necessário devido ao jeito como C++ organiza os objetos na memória.

Quando você declara uma variável em C++ é necessário que o compilador saiba quanto espaço será necessário para armazenar aquela informação para que ele possa reservar o espaço na pilha.

Sendo assim, para que seja possível declarar variáveis do tipo de uma classe é necessário poder calcular o seu tamanho e consequentemente que todos os seus membros sejam visíveis naquele ponto do código.

Vale ressaltar que uma variável do tipo `OlaMundo *` não é do tipo da classe (o tipo é ponteiro para objeto do tipo `OlaMundo`), sendo assim o compilador só precisa saber o tamanho que um ponteiro ocupa quando esta variável esta sendo declarada, já que o tamanho de ponteiros para dados independe do tipo do dado, e portanto não é necessário que a definição da classe esteja visível, apenas sua declaração.

> Por que não é possível declarar os dados membros private (`std::string mensagem`) na implementação (`private.cpp`)?

Além do problema já mencionado, outro problema seria como limitar quem pode inserir membros na classe caso fosse possível essa separação ?

O que aconteceria, por exemplo, se o arquivo `private1.cpp` adicionasse uma variável membro `std::string mensagem` a classe `OlaMundo` e outro arquivo chamado `private2.cpp` adicionasse uma variável membro `char * mensagem` na mesma classe ? E se um desses arquivos estivesse compilado dentro de uma biblioteca ?

Para resolver problemas como esse, se limita o local da declaração de variáveis membros de uma classe.

Munidos de todas essas informações podemos entender o estado atual do C++: quando se define uma classe/estrutura devem ser especificados todos os seus membros, inclusive membro privados.

> Observação: O código private.cpp poderia ser feito da forma (retirando-se o mebro private do cabeçalho correspondente:
>
> ```
> #include "private.h"
> #include <iostream>
>
> std::string mensagem;
>
> OlaMundo::OlaMundo(std::string msgArg) {
>     mensagem = msgArg;
> }
>
> void OlaMundo::mostrarMsg() {
>     std::cout << "Olá, " << mensagem << "!" << std::endl;
> }
> ```
>
> Isso poderia ser considerado como uma boa engenharia em C++? O dado se tornou "private" por cabeçalho e não por definição de classe.

Como observado por você e dito pelo usuário [ctgPi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/25930/ctgpi) em sua resposta, esse código apresenta uma mudança de semântica com relação ao primeiro já que agora existe apenas uma instância da variável `mensagem` por programa e não uma por objeto do tipo `OlaMundo`. Sendo assim é impossível dizer qual é uma melhor prática de engenharia já que cada uma apresenta um comportamento diferente.

Comment: Não é impossível que bibliotecas diferentes definam métodos diferentes com o mesmo nome para a mesma classe: veja os _extension methods_ do C#, por exemplo. Além disso, outras linguagens (como C#, via classes parciais, ou Python, via _monkey patching_) permitem definir métodos ao longo de vários arquivos (ainda que o problema de namespacing seja responsabilidade do programador). C++ exige que a definição da classe esteja centralizada em um arquivo (e exposta aos usuários) porque referências a atributos são resolvidas em tempo de compilação (como é feito em C), e não em tempo de link-edição.

Answer (score 0):

A primeira e a segunda versão não são equivalentes — elas seriam mais próximas se `mensagem` fosse `static private`.

Mas sim, isso é um [problema conhecido com C++](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/class.html#fqa-7.4), que é agravado pelo fato de alterações na estrutura interna da classe forçarem a recompilação de **todo** o código que faz referência a essa classe (e, pra piorar, C++ não é exatamente uma linguagem de compilação rápida).

Talvez no fundo a sua pergunta seja “por que se usa tanto C++ até hoje apesar das deficiências?”; a resposta é que C++ foi inventada ainda em 1983; Java, por exemplo, só foi lançada em 1995 (e C# em 2000).

Talvez alguém com mais cabelos brancos do que eu aqui no pt.SO te dê melhor esse contexto, mas por muito tempo C++ foi a única linguagem com um certo nível de adoção, que permitia escrever código eficiente, próximo à máquina, e que operasse num nível acima de C puro; o Google lançou o [Go](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) em 2009 pra atacar esse nicho e corrigir algumas das deficiências de C++.

Comment: Dizer que "se usa tanto C++ até hoje apesar das deficiências" pois ela foi inventada primeiro é ignorar a realidade. Escolher uma linguagem não é questão de achar uma linguagem perfeita mas sim pesar os pros e contras de cada linguagem para a tarefa que você quer executar. A data tem certamente uma influência mas C++ oferece vantagens e desvantagens que quando ponderadas mostram que ela ainda é a linguagem mais apropriada para alguns setores, como desenvolvimento de jogos AAA e desenvolvimento de apps móveis multiplataforma eficientes.

Comment: Eu nunca disse o contrário. Eu trabalhei dois anos e meio no Google desenvolvendo código em C++ para o mecanismo de busca de lá; eu esqueci de enumerar alguma dessas vantagens no meu último parágrafo?

Answer (score 0):

O C++ exige que os membros privados sejam declarados no cabeçalho porque o **C++ permite alocar objetos na pilha**, então seu tamanho tem de ser conhecido de antemão por todos os clientes da classe. Se o tamanho da classe mudar, mesmo que seja por conta de uma modificação na lista de membros privados, todos os clientes têm de recompilar seu código.

Linguagens como o Objective-C ou Java só alocam objetos na pilha, e ainda por cima resolvem os membros públicos dinamicamente, então seu tamanho real, bem como as posições de cada membro dentro da estrutura do objeto, podem estar escondidas na implementação.

Na verdade **é possível esconder a parte privada** de uma classe C++ usando o "idioma Pimpl":

```
// cabeçalho público, fornecido aos clientes

class Publica_pimpl;

class Publica {
   public:
       ...
   private:
       Publica_pimpl* p;
};

// cabeçalho privado, que os clientes não precisam receber

class Publica_pimpl {
   ... seus membros e métodos privados aqui ...
};
```

Isolando a parte privada da classe numa classe separada, você pode modificá-la à vontade. Como o cabeçalho da classe Publica nunca muda, os clientes nunca precisam recompilar o código; basta distribuir uma versão atualizada da biblioteca compilada (supondo que a classe seja distribuída como biblioteca e não como fonte). Qualquer mudança em Publica_pimpl só afeta a própria biblioteca.

Os guidelines de grandes projetos C++ recomendam sempre adicionar um ponteiro Pimpl em toda classe, mesmo que não seja utilizado num primeiro momento, porque é uma escapatória para quase toda modificação que se fizer necessária, sem quebrar a compatibilidade com os clientes existentes.